# Websphere Portal generating url longer than 2k

Tags: internet-explorer, websphere, portal

We have a data entry portlet that occassionally generates urls in excess of the 2k limit enforced by Internet Explorer.

Is there any way to stop these excessively long urls from being generated without loss of functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be to upgrade or ensure that the page is simple enough not to trigger the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use POST instead of GET? If not, what are the long URLs pointing to ?

Comment: I am using POST. The urls are generated by standard portal jsp tags and contain encoded data allowing for consistant navigation (back button etc).

Answer (score 0):

Which version of WebSphere Portal are you using?

The new Portal 6.1 has a feature called "Friendly URLs" that is supposed to alleviate some of these issues. I haven't had a chance to research it yet (we're still struggling to get 6.0 in place) but it might be useful to you.

See also:

[Are there any Portal products that can generate friendly URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334987/are-there-any-portal-products-that-can-generate-friendly-urls)

Comment: Unfortunately we are stuck with Portal 5.1